# Minor bug with the moderator flag display

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, comment-flags

I'm looking at my flag display in the moderator tools (on math.SE), and for one flagged comment, the little indicator showing what actions have been taken so far appears as follows:

[image]

Another occurrence I just found: if I switch to the 10k view of the current flags, there is a link to switch back to the full moderator view, and it appears as follows:

[image]

The `ê` is really more of a curiosity than an annoyance, but I figure it could be looked into. Perhaps it is intended to be the ♦ symbol? At any rate, this is very low priority - I assume the appearance of these `ê`'s is not affecting anyone other than moderators.

Comment: It is indeed the ♦ symbol: [screen capture from the Programmers mod dashboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qhv3.png).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just checked this in Firefox and it appears correctly; but in Chrome (where I took my screenshots) the effect persists through refreshing and restarting the browser. Also, the ♦ symbol has appeared correctly in Chrome for me on the site in the past, and in fact it is displaying correctly for me right here on this post - it's only in the actual mod dashboard where I'm now having this problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Chrome?

Comment: @jadarnel27: It's version 16.0.912.77.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the diamond correctly here? ♦

We're using a standard Unicode escape for html when displaying the mod diamonds, i.e. `&#9830;`

Seems that [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes) recommends against this, however:

> It is almost always preferable to use an encoding that allows you to represent characters in their normal form, rather than using character entity references or NCRs.

So I'll have to get back with you after talking to everyone on the team as to *why* we're doing that.

Comment: Looks fine here, and it's back to normal on the mod dashboard too. Seems likely it was some local thing on my end, but I appreciate your looking into it.

Comment: Isn't it because HTML entities are so much easier to type on a keyboard?

Comment: Wait, it's back to `ê` again. Huh.

Comment: @Bolt just think of the savings, man!  6 characters on every diamond displayed... BANDWIDTH BONANZA!

Comment: @Zev it's displayed incorrect on this answer, too?

Comment: Nope, it was just on the dashboard - it's been displaying fine here the whole time. (It's now currently working again on the dashboard)

Comment: It's also been working consistently when it appears next to my name - seems to only be the dashboard (back to not working - sorry, don't mean to make you crazy, I'll stop with the updates)

Comment: I'm now seeing a box: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lvzFy.png